# Would I need to change the id_rsa file private key when generating a new Personal Access Token on git for passphrase?

Tags: git, github

So I am trying to `git clone` a repo, and I run into:

```
(py38-stable) user@jupyter:~/local$ git clone git@github.com:user/user2.git
Cloning into 'user2'...
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.223.2' to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I can't seem to remember my passphrase.

Two questions:

1. One approach around this is to generate a new Personal Access Token on git?
2. If so, when I generate a new Personal Access Token, would I need to replace the private key inside the `id_rsa` file? And if so, what do I replace it with?
   Because when I generate a new Personal Access Token, this Personal Access Token is very short compared to the content of the `private key` inside the `id_rsa` file.
3. Is this `Personal Access Token` the passphrase? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first understand the basics:

- You can connect to GitHub repos via ssh or https
- In order to connect to GitHub repos via ssh, you will need an ssh keypair and possibly a passphrase:

  - private key (known only to you, never share this with anyone)
  - public key (this is the part of the key you can share)
  - (optionally) a passphrase
- In order to connect to GitHub repos via

  - username & password **or**
  - personal access token

So, passphrase is for further protecting your ssh key and personal access token is a token for https authentication.

Now, if you have an ssh keypair that you already generated whose passphrase you forgot, then there is no way to recover it. You can generate a new ssh keypair instead, with or without passphrase. If you generate one with a passphrase, make sure you will not forget it.

If you want to have an ssh key and use it for authentication, then your public key will need to end up as a new line at the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (see more [here](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/authorized-keys-file#configuring-authorized_keys))

Otherwise, you can also switch to using the https protocol and authenticate either with a username/password or a personal access token. The advantage of having a personal access token instead of a username/password authentication is that if, for any reason someone is able to track or find out how you authenticated, then the leaked information will "only" be the personal access token that you can invalidate with your user instead of losing access to your GitHub user (if the hackers are successful in locking you out from your own account).

If you have access to your user and you have the rights you need to a repo, then you should be able to generate a new ssh key, a personal access token for your https cnnections or to use the not recommended username/password authentication for repos.